# Communication between excel and silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, excel

I am developing an application  where i need to get data from excel to my silverlight oob application and after manuplation send it back to excel.

I am able to do this using with com automation factory classes. But the problem is we have already developed some logics for grabing data from wcf and odbc so we want to track changes by WCF service.
The requirement is: if i changes data into excel that will be reflected into silverlight and if I change data into silverlight that need to be reflected into excel, using an WCF Service.

Is it possible to **communicate Excel to Silverlight or vice versa with WCF service** ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a hard time understanding what you want to accompish, but I'll try to answer the question as is.

It's possible to call a WCF service from both SL and an Excel .NET application (COM Add-in or VSTO). It's also possible to host a WCF service right in Excel .NET app (at least, should be: you can do it in a console app, so why not?). So basically you can use WCF to communicate between SL OOB and Excel .NET app. But the question is: why do it that way? I have a feeling that it's much faster and safer to just rewrite your logic so you won't need WCF at all...

Comment: @Jhoonjhar unfortunately I do not have time for that. But I'm sure you can google it out.

Answer (score 0):

upload the excel file though silverlight to WCF and then use OpenXml to do what you want with it. Then redownload it.