# Communication between excel addin and electron based desktop application

Tags: javascript, excel, electron, add-in, vba

**Overview**

Is it possible for an Excel Add-in (or VBA script etc) to communicate with Electron based desktop application? I have found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070531/interprocess-communication-between-excel-c-sharp-application) related to communication between excel and C# application, [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572466/communication-between-excel-and-silverlight) between Excel and Silverlight, but nothing related to excel and electron app.

**Details**

Is it possible for Excel add-in to launch Electron application and pass on all the workbook data, and current cell number? And can Eelectron application after performing complex analysis of data return results to Excel so that it can be updated there?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. The question is however not specific to Excel; so you probably need to check out how to communication between an node based app, and other apps. Some options: ipc, sockets, pipes, queues, database, files. All of them kind of suck. So you better avoid using node.js for building Excel Addins.

Comment: So an excel add-in can call rest-based node server and work fine. But is there any way for the add-in to communicate with locally install electron app? Can you provide some reference/article where this issue might be discussed?

Comment: Yes, it can communicate with local app using ipc, sockets, pipes, queues, database, files. You might be looking for "how do I communicate from a node-based app with other local apps". The mentioned reset-based server is also valid choice (it is a part of "sockets" option) - you can expose a localhost server from your addin (for example -
 an HttpListener based), and let the node app communicate with that.

Comment: Awesome. Can you provide some articles/reference where this thing can be found?